# How do I display information for user accounts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, user-roles

I have a website I'm developing and have roles setup with one group "admin" that I want to be able to select a user and display information about that user...name, password, security question and so on.  What would be the easiest way to get this done?  Also, I have modified the default login steps to include a few additional requirements, such as first and last name, company, etc.  I would like the "admin" group to be able to view all this information quickly and easily so if a customer from another company calls us saying they fired that person, we can remove the user based on their actual name, not username.

**EDIT**
Can I do something like:

```
MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(RegisterUser.UserName);
user.Comment = fnametxt.Text.ToString() + " " + lnametxt.Text.ToString() + " " + companytxt.Text.ToString();
System.Web.Security.Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

to store the additional info then recall the user.Comment from the sql database when needed?

Comment: What part exactly are you having trouble with?  Where are the users/roles data being stored?  This look like a fairly straightforward, standard spec that should be relatively easy to implement

Comment: I should have added I'm fairly new to asp.net.  I know how to get the username of current users, where would I store the additional information that contains their first and last names and their company name?

Comment: You should use a Profile Provider to store the additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that what you are looking for is a Profile provider.  This can be used to store addition information about users such as first and last names and other miscellanea.

in Web.config

```
<profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"
             type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
             connectionStringName="yourConnectionString"<!--Same as membership provider-->
             applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="string"/>
        <add name="LastName" type="string"/>
        <add name="Company" type="string"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

Add/edit profile properties:

```
var username = User.Identity.Name;
ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(username);
profile["FirstName"] = "John";
profile["LastName"] = "Smith";
profile["Company"] = "WalMart";
profile.Save();
```

Read profile properties:

```
var username = User.Identity.Name;
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(username);
var firstName = profile["FirstName"] as string;
var lastName = profile["LastName"] as string;
var company = profile["Company"] as string;
```

I think this would be the way to go and a bit cleaner and easier to maintain that using comments.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you haven't said "Where" you're storing your membership information but I'll assume it's in a SQL DAtabase using the out-of-the-box Membership & RoleProvider schema that's generating by aspnet_regsql.exe

Aside from using [the built-in user configuration tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in an ASP.NET Website, there are a few 3rd party applications you can use to interact with your membership users.

I used [MyWSAT](http://mywsat.codeplex.com/) a long time ago but it doesn't appear to be maintained any more.

One thing you should be aware of, is that you can't & shouldn't be able to display the "password" of an end-user in your system.